# MySQL: How to pass parameter to a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger, mysql-5.7

I have a table on a `mysql 5.7` db, containing say **athletes** with their mean, max, avg times in a specific sport. I have another table that lists some **calculated** statistics based on those values.

I managed to do the calculcations that end up on the second using stored procedures. I use as input parameter to the stored procedure the athlete's name.

So when in the first table, an athlete is inserted (with his/her avg/min/max times) or his/her values are updated and I run the stored procedure, the later updates the **statistics** table.

My question is how to achieve the same result with **triggers**?

I guess it is feasible/easy to update the entire table on each insert or update of the first table. What would be more efficient performance-wise, would be on each :

```
INSERT into table1 values (..) where athlete_name="John Do"

(...)

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (...)
```

Run a trigger in the pseudocode form :

```
INSERT into statistics_table values (..) where athlete_name="John Do"

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (...)
```

How can the the `athlete_name="John Do"` be passed to the trigger dynamically, to avoid update the entire statistics table?

Comment: A trigger is fired by an action on a table,you cannot run it or pass a parameter to it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass any parameters to a trigger and the `insert` statement does not support the `where` clause either.

Having said this, a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) can pick up the user's name from the record being inserted / updated / deleted using `NEW.athlete_name` or `OLD.athlete_name` (whichever is required) and use that to call a stored procedure:

> Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access
>   columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL
>   extensions to triggers; they are not case-sensitive.
>
> In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old
>   row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no
>   new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to
>   the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to
>   the columns of the row after it is updated.
>
> A column named with OLD is read only. You can refer to it (if you have
>   the SELECT privilege), but not modify it. You can refer to a column
>   named with NEW if you have the SELECT privilege for it. In a BEFORE
>   trigger, you can also change its value with SET NEW.col_name = value
>   if you have the UPDATE privilege for it. This means you can use a
>   trigger to modify the values to be inserted into a new row or used to
>   update a row. (Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger
>   because the row change will have already occurred.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create triggers that fire after each insert or update on the parent table (athletes). Within each trigger, you can access the value of column athlete_name on the record that was just created or changed, and then invoke your stored procedure using `CALL()`.

Here is a code sample for such an `INSERT` trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER athletes_upd AFTER INSERT ON athletes 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL my_procedure(NEW.athlete_name);
END;
```

`UPDATE` trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER athletes_upd AFTER UPDATE ON athletes 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL my_procedure(NEW.athlete_name);  -- or maybe OLD.athlete_name ?
END;
```

Comment: I like this approach however I think it is discouraged: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10663/160882